# Reinstallation of script wipes out databases I have populated

Tags: database, mysql

I am setting up a website with a script that creates several MySQL databases during installation, and from time to time I have to reinstall the script several times because of changes I've made. During the re-installation, the install script wipes all the groups and categories in those groups. I have to manually input the groups and categories again.

This is two instances of the code and both wipe out databases that I have created and populated.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category_name` varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `group_id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category_name` varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `group_id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you `DROP TABLE` then it's not going to exist hence it being created and appears as if the table was wiped. In the second part nothing will happen if the table already exists.

Comment: It's obvious that your script is indiscriminate; it drops the table.

However, if you're serious about database change management, have a look at [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it nukes it; you call

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
```

That's what `DROP TABLE` does: destroy the table.

Answer (score 0):

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`; 
was in the original script and after I discovered the problem I removed that line of code and included only the second example above. It still wipes out the category database even with that line of code removed.

Confusing?!

Thanks,